# css hover for entire li element with padding

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to give the menu elements a hover, but they are also having a `padding: 10px;` and as the result of that the `:hover: background-color:` will start from the 10px padding.

Any idea how to solve the problem? Here's a jsfiddle demo for that: http://jsfiddle.net/eufqg7d9/

Comment: So you only want the elements to change color when the cursor is over the text?

Comment: Not excatly. 
This would be the result i am trying to get. 

http://people.inf.elte.hu/zirtaai/photobucket/result.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the default padding of the UL. You can either explicitly set this to padding: 0 or use a reset like http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.

Here is your fiddle with a this reset applied: http://jsfiddle.net/h3erxugg/

You can also skip adding extra classes (like "list-item") and simply target the 'li' element itself within the #menu "namespace". Here's an example of what I mean:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Menü #1</li>
    <li>Menü #2</li>
    <li>Menü #3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And then the corresponding CSS would look something like this:

```
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#menu li {
  padding: 10px;
}

#menu li:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: thanks, worked! yeah, your solution is much cleaner! :)

Comment: @RichardZilahi Then you should change it to the Best Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eufqg7d9/3/

```
li.menu-item:hover {
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Since it was unclear what you were asking I have made you another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eufqg7d9/6/. This basically creates the effect of your picture.

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;    
}

li {
    margin: 0;
}

div#main {

    width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

div#menu {

    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
}

ul.menu-list {

    list-style: none;
}

li span {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

li.menu-item {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}

li.menu-item:hover {

    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to update this portion of css.

```
ul.menu-list {
   list-style: none;
   padding-left: 0;
}
```

I have added `padding-left: 0;` to remove the padding on the left side.